# Whats the simplest way when writing & reading a 2D-boolean-Array to a CSV File?

Tags: java, arrays, parsing, csv

I'd like to write a 2-Dimensional boolean-Array to a CSV file.
Im using Apache Commons' CSVParser. The Problem is that I couldnt find a built-in way to turn the Array into something that can be written into an CSV-File and then later converted back.

So is there a way apart from using `Arrays.deepToString(...)` and then writing a complicated and error-prone function to parse the Array?

It would be great if `boolean[][] array = Arrays.parse<boolean[][]>(Arrays.deepToString(oldArray))` existed...

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [uniVocity-parsers](http://www.univocity.com/pages/parsers-tutorial) to write/read your booleans.

```
public static void main(String ... args){
    CsvWriterSettings writerSettings = new CsvWriterSettings();

    ObjectRowWriterProcessor writerProcessor = new ObjectRowWriterProcessor(); // handles rows of objects and conversions to String.
    writerProcessor.convertAll(Conversions.toBoolean("T", "F")); // will write "T" and "F" instead of "true" and "false"

    writerSettings.setRowWriterProcessor(writerProcessor);

    CsvWriter writer = new CsvWriter(writerSettings);
    writerSettings.setHeaders("A", "B", "C", "D");

    String line1 = writer.processRecordToString(true, false, false, true);
    String line2 = writer.processRecordToString(false, false, true, true);

    System.out.println("### Rows written ###");

    System.out.println(line1);
    System.out.println(line2);

    // Now, let's read these lines

    CsvParserSettings parserSettings = new CsvParserSettings();

    ObjectRowListProcessor readerProcessor = new ObjectRowListProcessor(); // handles conversions from String to Objects and adds the result to a list
    readerProcessor.convertAll(Conversions.toBoolean("T", "F")); //reads "T" and "F" back to true and false

    parserSettings.setRowProcessor(readerProcessor);

    CsvParser parser =  new CsvParser(parserSettings);
    parser.parseLine(line1); //handled by the readerProcessor
    parser.parseLine(line2); //handled by the readerProcessor

    System.out.println("### Rows parsed ###");

    List<Object[]> rows = readerProcessor.getRows();
    for(Object[] row : rows){
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(row));
    }
}
```

The code above produces:

```
### Rows written ###
T,F,F,T
F,F,T,T
### Rows parsed ###
[true, false, false, true]
[false, false, true, true]
```

Note: you shouldn't need to explicitly set the headers when writing, but I just found (and fixed) this in the [master branch of the project](https://github.com/uniVocity/univocity-parsers)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know of a built in way to do this, so my first instinct  would be to write an arrayToCsv method and a csvToArray method.

The arrayToCsv method might look like this:

```
public String arrayToCsv(boolean[][] array) {
  String csv = "";
  for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
      csv = csv + array[i][j]; //java will autobox and convert this for you
      if (j == (array[i].length - 1))
        csv = csv + ",";
    }
    if (i == (array.length - 1))
      csv = csv + "\n";
  }
  return csv;
}
```

**Edit:** Updated arrayToCsv method to include @Clashsoft's suggestion:

```
public String arrayToCsv(boolean[][] array) {
  int initialSize = array.length * array[0].length * 7; //longest possible string*
  StringBuilder csv = new StringBuilder(initialSize);
  for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
    for (int j = 0; j < array[i].length; j++) {
      csv.append(array[i][j]);
      if (j == (array[i].length - 1))
        csv.append(",");
    }
    if (i == (array.length - 1))
      csv.append("\n");
  }
  return csv.toString();
}
```

*Note: the length of the string will always be between arraySize * len("true,") and arraySize * len("false,\n"), although actual lengths near the endpoints would likely be rare.  I opted for the longest possible size to initialize the StringBuilder to optimize efficiency by preventing it from ever having to resize itself.  I think the wasted space will generally have a negligible impact.

The corresponding csvToArray method would be:

```
public boolean[][] csvToArray(String csv) {
  String[] rows = csv.split("\n");
  boolean[][] array = new boolean[rows.length][]; 
  int r = 0;
  for (String row : rows) {
    String[] temp = row.split(",");
    for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++)
      array[r][i] = Boolean.parseBoolean(temp[i]);
    r++;
  }
  return array;
}
```

I haven't had a chance to compile and run these so I can't make any guarantees.  I will do it when I get home, and I will make edits if there are any errors.  Hope this helps; good luck!

Comment: I recommend using a `StringBuilder` to generate the CSV as this saves you a lot of time + memory.

Comment: If there is no other solution I will implement it myself using your solution so thanks very much!

Comment: Agreed on the StringBuilder.  I will edit to reflect that in the solution when I shortly.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the code, that works with apache common CSV lib.

```
import java.io.BufferedWriter;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.PrintWriter;

import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVFormat;
import org.apache.commons.csv.CSVPrinter;




public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        Appendable stream = new PrintWriter(new BufferedWriter(new FileWriter("foo.out")));
        CSVPrinter printer = new CSVPrinter(stream, CSVFormat.DEFAULT);
        boolean [][] data = new boolean[5][5];
        for (int i=0; i<5; i++){
            for (int j=0; j<5; j++){
                data[i][j] = i ==j;
                printer.print(data[i][j]);
            }
            printer.println();
        }
        printer.flush();
        printer.close();

    }

}
```

and here is the output it generates:

```
true,false,false,false,false
false,true,false,false,false
false,false,true,false,false
false,false,false,true,false
false,false,false,false,true
```

I hope it helps =]